# Bulid String Variable from text and int Value

Tags: php

I have the following problem. I want to create a loop which sets the value of a string variable to: `textBox + number` for example `textBox2`. I have this code now:

```
 <?php
$counter=$_POST["Counter"];

While ($counter > 0){
    (string)$textbox='textBox'+(string)$counter;
    $referent = $_POST[$textbox];
    echo $referent;
    $counter = $counter - 1;
}
```

But the following error appears:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eventtool\add_new_element.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eventtool\add_new_element.php on line 6

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eventtool\add_new_element.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Eventtool\add_new_element.php on line 6
```

Can someone help me please, I don't get a solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: String concatenation is done via `.`, not via `+`. Also, you don't need those casts.

Comment: "textBox".$counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noticed in comments, concatenation of strings in php is done with `.`, and if you do some concatenation php converts variables' values to strings. So, you can simplify your `while` to:

```
while ($counter > 0){
    $textbox = 'textBox' . $counter;
    $referent = $_POST[$textbox];
    echo $referent;
    $counter = $counter - 1;
}
```

Also, as I see that you iterate over `$_POST` variables that are named similarly: `textBox1`, `textBox2`, `textBox3` etc., I advise you to rebuild your html form and use `[]` in textboxes' names

```
<textarea name="textBox[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="textBox[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="textBox[]"></textarea>
```

In this case you can iterate over your `$_POST['textBox']` with a simple `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_POST['textBox'] as $textbox) {
    echo $textbox;
}
```

Also, as you can see, here you don't need `$_POST['counter']`.

Comment: You expect me to guess error message?

Comment: Thanks for the answer i got an Error message for the foreach solution now i tried it like this:

`$counter=$_POST["Counter"];
$id =  1;
While ($id <= $counter){
    $textbox='textBox'.$id;
    $referent = $_POST[$textbox];
    echo $referent;
    $id = $id + 1;
}`

Html is like this:
<div id="responce">
 </div>

Comment: and js like this:
and JS:

`var countBox =1;
var boxName = 0;
function addInput()
{
     var boxName="textbox[]"; 
     document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="'+boxName+'" placeholder="Add '+countBox+' Referent" autofocus required /></div><br/>';
     document.getElementById("Counter").value = countBox; 
     countBox += 1;
}


</script>`

Comment: but i get the error undefined Index

Comment: Your code is unreadable, edit your question please.

Comment: And `id`s of elements are __not__ passed to server, only `names`.